# Array returns 'undefined' result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

```
Array E = ["lib/img/Brand/A.png", "lib/img/Brand/B.png", "lib/img/Brand/C.png"];
Array F = ["lib/img/offer/A1.png", "lib/img/offer/B1.png", "lib/img/offer/C1.png"];
Array G = ["lib/img/print/A2.png", "lib/img/print/B2.png", "lib/img/print/C2.png"];
```

Secondly, I have created 2 img tag to display 2 randomly generated array item from Array E.

Thirdly, when I clicked on either one of the randomly generated image from Array E in the img tag, an image from Array F will be displayed.

E.g:
     img tag is showing item A.png and item C.png from Array E, and when i clicked on  item A.png from Array E, item A1.png from Array F will be displayed.

Lastly, when i clicked the item shown from Array F, the corresponding item from Array G will be displayed.

E.g:
     img tag is showing item B.png and item A.png from Array E, and when i clicked on  item B.png from Array E, item B1.png from Array F will be displayed. And When i clicked on item B1.png from Array F, item B2.png will be displayed.

***What I have done:***

I have managed to display 2 randomly generated items from Array E and when i click on either of the image item from Array E, I am able to get the correct image item from Array F.

***Issue:***

However, when i clicked on the image item from Array F, i am unable to get any image item from Array G, when i do a console.log for Array G, it returns a result of undefined. And none of the item in Array G is actually append with Array F.

Could I please get some help in what i have done wrong.

***Code: ***

```js
Array_E = ["lib/img/Brand/A.png", "lib/img/Brand/B.png", "lib/img/Brand/C.png"];
Array_F = ["lib/img/offer/A1.png", "lib/img/offer/B1.png", "lib/img/offer/C1.png"];
Array_G = ["lib/img/print/A2.png", "lib/img/print/B2.png", "lib/img/print/C2.png"];
var Brand_list = [];
var printOfferFrame = "";

//Randomised Brand Offer
//Auto populate into brand container once randomised
$('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
  random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Array_E.length);
  console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);

  var Brand = Array_E[random_BrandIndex];

  Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);
  $(img).attr('src', Brand).show();
});

function selectBrand(index) {
  selectedOffer = Array_F[Brand_list[index - 1]];
  console.log("selectedOffer: " + selectedOffer);
  $("#Pa_Description").attr('src', selectedOffer).show();

  //THIS IS THE PART I AM HAVING AN ISSUE, RETURN RESULT IS UNDEFINED
  var printOfferSelected = Brand_list[Brand_list.length - 1];
  console.log("printOfferSelected : " + printOfferSelected);

  printOfferFrame = Array_G[parseInt(Array_F[Brand_list[index - 1]])];

  console.log("printOfferFrame : " + Array_G[printOfferSelected - 1]);
}

function PrinOffer() {
  ajax_Print();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="BrandDescription" class="BrandMenu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=9; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <img id="Pa_Description" class="BrandDescription" style="position:absolute; width: 1080px; height:762px; top:500px; left:0px; z-index=99;">

  <button class="Print" onclick="PrintOffer()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: provide working example

Comment: I think you are excluding some code here, for example `BrandNameArray` isn't defined as the error stated. Also I've included jQuery in your example.

Comment: in click of image how selectBrand() function identifying that displayed image is brand so that has to display offer image or image is offer so that it has to display print image?

Comment: @RajeshKathiriya I don't get your question

Comment: @RajeshKathiriya, if i have not misunderstood you, the following line of code: `selectedOffer = Array_F[Brand_list[index - 1]];` will take the value that has been stored from `Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);`, to get the offer image

Comment: You are using same img tag for all three image display you are just changing src attribute, on first click you will change image 'brand' to 'offer', now when you click 'offer' image still same  selectBrand() function is called how you will identify that now you have to display 'print' image inside selectBrand()  function ?

Comment: @RajeshKathiriya, there is a button `onclick = PrintOffer()` and will call on method PrintOffer

Comment: Did you say : `return result is undefined` ?

Comment: @php-dev yes, the return result for console.log for Array G is undefined

Comment: Also, what is `Array_G[parseInt(Array_F[Brand_list[index - 1]])];` supposed to do?

Comment: but you are saying "When i clicked on item B1.png from Array F, item B2.png will be displayed." you are not clicking button you are clicking image right ?

Comment: @php-dev, because there are 2 img tags-> `GameBand_1` & `GameBrand_2`, so there are 2 indexes which the random generated image will append to, hence, I need to get the index that is stored in `Brand_list` and allow Array_F to append to  `Brand_list` , such that if the index is showing index= 2 in brandlist it will be showing the same index number in Array_G

Comment: @RajeshKathiriya, yes, I am clicking an image

Comment: so when will PrintOffer() function will called ?

Comment: @RajeshKathiriya, at page id = BrandDescription, hence PrintOffer will be called when the button in page id = BrandDescription is clicked

Comment: But `parseInt` will always return `NaN` in your case!!

Comment: @php-dev, yes!!that is exactly the issue that i am facing. and i have no idea on how to recitfy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
Array_E = ["lib/img/Brand/A.png", "lib/img/Brand/B.png", "lib/img/Brand/C.png"];
Array_F = ["lib/img/offer/A1.png", "lib/img/offer/B1.png", "lib/img/offer/C1.png"];
Array_G = ["lib/img/print/A2.png", "lib/img/print/B2.png", "lib/img/print/C2.png"];


//Randomised Brand Offer
//Auto populate into brand container once randomised
$('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
  random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Array_E.length);
  console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);
  var Brand = Array_E[random_BrandIndex];
  $(img).attr({'src':Brand,'data-index':random_BrandIndex}).show();
});
$('.GameWinBrand_innerScroll img').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  index = $(this).attr('data-index');//get index of the img
  $("#Pa_Description").attr('src', Array_F[index]).show();//here you may need to use parent to show it
   console.log("printOfferSelected : " + Array_F[index]);
  console.log("printOfferFrame "+Array_G[index]);//alert the image from the index provided by the index attribute
});

function PrinOffer() {
  ajax_Print();
}
```

```css
.GameWinBrand_Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 950px;
  left: 286px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
.BrandMenu {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=98);
  opacity: 0.98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" >
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" >
  </div>
</div>

<div id="BrandDescription" class="BrandMenu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=9; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <img id="Pa_Description" class="BrandDescription" style="position:absolute; width: 1080px; height:762px; top:500px; left:0px; z-index=99;">

  <button class="Print" onclick="PrintOffer()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont get your meaning to the solution. and I would like to try to refrain from changing the code too much.. your solution is provided based on individual img id, while, my code is based on an event handler "selectBrand(index)"

Comment: secondly, i have tried as well, and the return value is always at -1

Comment: i see, indexOf doesn't find the image because the src is absolute

Comment: meaning? cause I need to see the file path name of the last array when I clicked on the second array

Comment: so for `$(#"GameBrand_1")` will be the same as well? and I will have to remove my `function selectBrand(index)`?

Comment: Yes something similar

Comment: alright, i will give it a try. So does that mean, the current functional method of  `function selectBrand(index)` could be messy and result in unwanted errors?